# When editing an object, what is best way to keep record of ObjectID being edited in order to Save later?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a page with a gridview, and a list of orders.
When the user clicks edit on an Order in the gridview,
a list of textboxes is populated for the user, containing details for the specific order he selected.
The user can then press the update button and that Order he was editing will then be updated to the DB.

There are many other pages like this, e.g. Invoices, Products etc.

My question: I would like to find the proper way the keep track of the ID of the object I'm editing.
I'm wondering whether it would be a good idea to store the ID of the Item in the update button.

```
btnOrderUpdate.Attributes.Clear();
btnOrderUpdate.Attributes.Add("OrderID", orderID.ToString());
```

When I update, I need to get the OrderID again, e.g.

```
var orderID = btnOrderUpdate.Attributes("OrderID");
```

I would like to stay away from cookies, as there are limits to how many cookies I can use, and I have not been able to encrypt cookies successfully.

I also dot't want to use a hiddenfield which I update, as this easily gives the user the ID if he views the source.

What would you recommend me to use? The Attribute was just an idea I had, what is the standard way to do it?

Comment: WebForms? MVC? What framework are you using?

Comment: Sesstion, or ViewState (what = hidden field).

Answer (score 1):

You have already ruled out using hidden forms, which is a standard convention in this case. For that reason I also doubt you'd want to store it in the query string since that's plainly visible.

In your situation I'd recommend storing it in the Session. That should keep it active for about 20 minutes if the user's session isn't in a sliding window. Once it's no longer needed you can also remove it from the session.

Comment: thanks, so you would use hidden forms (as in hiddenfield control?) rather? Do people encrypt or scramble the hiddenfield values? or is it good practice just to keep it as plain text in a hiddenfield? What if I edit the value of the hiddenfield?

Comment: I generally keep it as plain text in a hidden field if I need to access it on the server in a temporary scope. You can encrypt it or scramble it if you think it's important to do so. Because it's in a hidden field as long as you've set runat to server it is always accessible in the code behind so you'll still receive updated values.

Answer (score 0):

You can exploit `System.Web.HttpContext` to fulfill your requirement. When the <kbd>Update</kbd> button is pressed, just save the (ObjectId, Value) as (key, value) pair in the `HttpContext.Items` dictionary in the following way:

```
HttpContext.Items["OrderID"] = orderID;
```

After that, when you need to save the values, just loop through the keys of `HttpContext.Items` with the corresponding `OrderId`s and save the values accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

if you want to keep orderID in page scope use ViewState

```
ViewState["orderID"] = orderID;
```

and server scope use Session

```
Session["orderID"] = orderID;
```